# How to Android BLE Passive scan?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, external

While scanning for advertising data with startLeScan method,
this method also request to pheripheral device for scan response data.
I only want to scan for advertising data.
I don't want to send response request to peripheral device.
and peripheral device can't change advertise mode.

According Bluetooth 4.0 Core spec, There exists passive scan mode.
https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=282159

And also, android has parameter that determines scan type.

And Active Scanning is android's default scan mode.
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/stack/btm/btm_ble_gap.c#327

How to use passive scan mode?

or

Possible to change or add in btm_ble_gap.c in external folder?

please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the Bluetooth stack internally supports passive scan, there is no public API available to use for apps for some reason.

Comment: I want to know how to change or add btm_ble_gap.c in external folder.

Comment: what's the way to change or add btm_ble_gap.c?

Comment: You need to create a custom Android ROM for that. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I must do that.

Comment: The feature what i want is Android device do passive scan usally, and
Send 'Scan Response Request' when i want.

Comment: Sorry for my english. My english is not well.